# Unsubscribe from rabbit queue when machine is shut down

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq

I am running rabbitmq through AMQP gem on 3 worker machines. When the machines are rebooted, my queue shows that workers are only added, not unsubscribed. For example, say each machine runs 5 workers:

When I boot 3 machines, I have 15 workers subscribed to the queue
When I shut down all 3 machines, I still have 15 workers subscribed to the queue
When I reboot the 3 machines, I now have 30 workers subscribed to the queue

In reality, I should only have 15 workers.

How can I ensure that my connection to my task queue closes when the machine reboots/shuts down? I have tried:

```
  Signal.trap("INT") do #handles the ctrl c case
    connection.close do
      EM.stop { exit }
    end
  end

  Signal.trap("TERM") do #handles the reboot and shut down case
    connection.close do
      EM.stop { exit }
    end
  end
```

This does NOT work.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a [Consumer cancellation Notification](http://www.rabbitmq.com/extensions.html#consumer-cancel-notify) extension.

In your case, the clients has not been notified of the machines rebooting (in other words they have not received a 'basic.cancel' notification from the rabbitmq broker when the machines rebooted).

See the excerpts taken from the link above:

> an extension in which the broker will send to the client a basic.cancel in the case of such unexpected consumer cancellations. This is not sent in the case of the broker receiving a basic.cancel from the client. AMQP 0-9-1 clients don't by default expect to receive basic.cancel methods from the broker asynchronously, and so in order to enable this behaviour, the client must present a capabilities table in its client-properties in which there is a key consumer_cancel_notify and a boolean value true

I'm not a ruby programmer, but I reckon the java example in the link above should give you the full picture.